# Calling a function when component on screen - React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I call a function when the component is on screen. My component is a wrapper for an image, and I want to call a function to fetch the actual image on the server when on screen. ( or within a window around the actual screen), and call an other function ( to delete the image) when offscreen.

These component are wrapped into a ListView. What I do now is to call my fetch in ComponentDidMound, hence every images in my listView are downloaded, which is really bad.

Basically I have a list of images, and I want to keep only about 20 in memory and as I scroll, remove the images offscreen and download the new one.

How should I model this ?

Thanks!

Comment: We're not able to solve your problems for you, but if you provide some examples of what you've tried or have specific questions we'd be happy to help. I would look into the lifecycle methods of ListView, maybe the pageSize attributes too. You might want to check if componentWillUnmount gets fired for offscreen items as well.

Comment: I think you are looking for componentDidMount()